# why can I not use my generic in Record type

Tags: typescript

I'm currently trying to use a generic (that's based on an array of string) to create an object which has known keys.

I am getting the following error message:

`Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Record<T[number], string>'.`

What I am trying to do is something like:

```
const a = ["find", "delete", open"];
const n = new NamedItems<typeof a>(a)
// n.named_items will show and intellisense
{
    "find" : 0,
    "delete" : 1,
    "open" : 2
}
```

with the following code:

```
class NamedItems<T extends string[]> {
    constructor (private order_of_named_items : T) {
    }

    GET_ITEMS (inNumber : number) {
        return inNumber.toString();
    }

    get named_items () {
        const { GET_ITEMS } = this;
        const i = this.order_of_named_items;
        const obj : Record<T[number], string> = {};
        for (const index in this.order_of_named_items) {
            const name = this.order_of_named_items[index];
            Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {
                get : () => {
                    return GET_ITEMS(+index);
                },
            });
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your question is "why" then the error message should make this clear - an empty object is not assignable to that type because that type requires properties that an empty object doesn't have. If you're actually intending to ask how to solve it, the simplest fix is a type assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, unless `T` happens to be an empty array, then the value `{}` is definitely not going to be assignable to type `Record<T[number], string>`.  So the compiler is warning you about that.

It looks like your intent is to initialize `obj` as an empty object, and then gradually populate that object so that when you're done it truly will be of type `Record<T[number], string>`.  Unfortunately the compiler isn't smart enough to follow how the type of `obj` would evolve during your loop, so you can't do this initialization in a purely type-safe way.  If you want to *pretend* that `obj` is of type `Record<T[number], string>` even at the beginning when it's just an empty object, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell it so:

```
const obj = {} as Record<T[number], string>; // okay
```

This will make the error go away.

---

Note that your desired usage

```
const a = ["find", "delete", "open"];
const n = new NamedItems(a);
```

will not work how you want since the compiler will infer that `a` is of type `string[]`, and therefore `n.named_items` will be of type `Record<string, string>`.  If you want `T` to be an array of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), you will need to change how the compiler infers the type of `a`.  The easiest way is with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const a = ["find", "delete", "open"] as const;
// const a: readonly ["find", "delete", "open"]
```

If you want to pass that into `new NamedItems` then you should make `T` allow [`readonly` arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) (which will also allow regular arrays):

```
class NamedItems<T extends readonly string[]> { /* ... */ }
```

And *now* everything will work as you expect:

```
const n = new NamedItems(a)
console.log(n.named_items.find) // "0"
console.log(n.named_items["delete"]) // "1"
console.log(n.named_items.open)  // "2"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEByYFsCmATAkgFyQiAeAKtEgB5YB2KMATkmCgPZkgCe0EGVAlmQOYDaAXQB80AN4AoaFOjBG7KgFdgGelQAUABy4A3MFmiqUSKgH16AMxNlEqE5yw4AXNHwBKMZOkBfcZ6kBxAFF8EzR8QIBZAGU1blgFBAAjY2cyBOSqdwlpHOgaDAUqMmg49OMAOhUojm4eNVcAbj9oH2aeJAxoa2QUOwcIeo9c6VkydjFoIJCwyKiW6ABeaAwAC04IJuGpUfHOReW1iHLDYzNLbtt7bA3mnJ3O+kSAK33RL2hIaAAlJFkqFAIfDSSWMAgANGwarwhJstuZVNA1PcShQSCiDutjv9ThYrDZelccFlbltkRd9qtMSdTLiLgT+nxuEZiAJYVtpAB5Z6-DDlIzmbhIAAKVHoGmMGGYakeTwhFwh2XZW3aGGcgwWIkVSqV+UKxSmoXC0TUAGomSRGiTtV4wVbcl5LeyfOzdUUDM82S1xK1kWB9nwAEQCigBiEBowgDpIUPQANipBkAMCD4we5NAD06Zkck6YGcNDojBY0EDwZQMfDSEjWAr8cTAl8ZP2ZCQAHc4PjMNc1GBXOIdvRI+UQPQ6mRynS+tdymX3JnYwAGAP9uSDpDD0dqceTwkQQMRqNJudZgMARmXA6HI7HE-xU5wx3FZHc0HnAYATMugA)

Comment: What's the difference between `const obj : Record<T[number], Locator> = {};` and `const obj = {} as Record<T[number], string>;`

Comment: The first is a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) on the variable, whereas the latter is a type *assertion* on the initializing expression.   A type annotation is type safe (the compiler will yell at you if you assign the wrong type value to that variable) whereas a type assertion is less safe (it will let you "downcast" a value to something the compiler can't verify.) See the documentation for type assertions (linked in the answer) and the documentation of type annotations (linked in this comment) for more info.